# Liquid or bait traps for termites in a brick rowhouse surrounded by concrete

Tags: pest-control

Just found some termites in floorboards at my back door into the yard, along with a swarm at the threshold... and I am looking to do some Termite control.  I have a brick rowhouse with concrete pavers in the yard and concrete front area - so it would require drilling in stone for either treatment.

One exterminator says liquid is the way to go since Termites are already in the home and baits won't lure them away from such a juicy wood meal that is your home.

Another exterminator says bait traps are easier to install and just as effective since we know where the termites are already so we would just put it smack in the middle.

They both seem to say the other is wrong.  All things equal the baits are easier to install - but they all seem to have a slightly scammy annual maintenance contract...

Should I go with liquid Termidor - or is bait traps like Sentricon or Trelona really as effective (and easier)?

The price is not that big of an issue, I just want what's the best and most effective.

Comment: This is probably more of an opinion type question. Termites do swarm and may not be actually in your wood yet. You should get some kind of treatment to discourage them from staying for lunch. Having purchased several homes with known termite and ant damage I would suggest a professional exterminator be contacted as the repairs are not easy or cheap. The chemicals homeowners can purchase at least in my state are not very strong compared to the pro grade stuff.

Comment: I've been asking the professionals and they seem to give opposite responses - each professional saying the opposite of the other.  This is assuming professional-grade liquid or bait traps.

Comment: If professionals can’t agree then you can see how it is opinion based.

Comment: I guess I'm surprised that there is not any science behind these products.  It seems like it's easy enough to prove whether bait traps will work with an active infestation.

Comment: If you use the sellers web page I am sure thy will have data that backs there product.